# Hickory leaves for compost

Tags: leaves, compost, mulch

I've done some trimming on some hickory trees and now I have a bunch of leaves, and branches.
I would like to know if these leaves are good for composting to be used in the garden afterwards. Or is mulching them a better solution?

I'm not sure if these types of leaves could damage other plants, especially in the garden.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to composting but have read not to use hickory leaves or black walnut.  I'd use for mulch in flower beds.

Comment: I ended up mulching them.